# 2011 Moderator Elections - Town Hall Chat: 6pm UTC on the 29th

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we will be holding a Town Hall Chat session with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.  I am working with the candidates to find a time that allows the most participation.

**The Town Hall Chat will take place Saturday the 29th at 6pm UTC, or 1pm EST.**

[**(view on other timezones)**](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?month=1&day=29&year=2011&hour=18&min=0&sec=0&p1=0)

Here are the details so far:

- I have coordinated with the candidates and done the best I could with a best fit match.  <s>I would like to schedule this towards the beginning of the election phase. there are not enough candidates for a primary phase which means you'll jump right to the election phase.  This means that I am looking at the 28th-30th. As soon as I coordinate with the existing moderators and candidates to find a best fit based on availability, I will edit this post with details on the "when".</s>
- The Town Hall Chat will be a one-hour event using our [chat platform](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=gamedev.stackexchange.com).  You can register for the event [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/245/game-dev-town-hall-chat?tab=schedule).
- The format will be an open discussion.  Users are encouraged to pose questions to the candidate regarding their thoughts on moderation.
- After the chat session, the transcript of the event will be permanently linked here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who participated, particularly the candidates!  We had Tetrad, Ricket, and Noctrine in attendance.

The full transcript to the Town Hall Chat can be found [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/245).

Whether you were able to attend or are just reading the transcript now, I hope this helps get to know the candidates for your vote. (:

---

The following questions were asked (click to be taken directly to that point in the transcript):

- [What does GameDev.SE need to work on in order to grow?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/430810#430810)
- [How do you attract high-quality questions that show-off the site?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/430849#430849)
- [How do you avoid burnout?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/430874#430874)
- [How do you feel about the current level of moderation on the site?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/430896#430896)
- [What is your criteria for determining whether or not something is a Community Wiki question?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/430914#430914)
- [How would you handle a question another moderator closed that you feel shouldn't have been?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/430948#430948)
- [How do you handle having a binding vote while at the same time leading by example?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/431037#431037)
- [How do you balance using a binding vote too early with saving the community from itself?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/431130#431130)
- [How do you handle off-topic questions that get answers / lots of votes that the community wants?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/431227#431227)
- [How do you handle questions raised on meta about your moderation actions?](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/431308#431308)

Answer (score 1):

Was scheduling the chat during [GGJ](http://globalgamejam.org/) a good idea?

Comment: It's more likely a side effect of the time of the elections.  Also I'm guessing that Rebecca took into account when the moderator candidates said they were available, so at least for us, it isn't that big of a deal.

Comment: Actually in my case, yes. I cleared my weekend for the GGJ and I'm happy to take an hour out of my day for this, whereas I might have otherwise been busy.